# Не корректный jQuery селектор

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такая разметка:

```
<button class="up_count_but">+</button> 
<button class="down_count_but">-</button> 
<button class="buy_button" type="submit" value="">
  <img src="images/bin.png" alt="">
</button>
<div class="count">
  <input type="text" class="c_count" value="2"></span>  
  <span>шт.</span>  
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с классом `up_count_but`, значение в `input.c_count` увеличивалось на единицу.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up_count_but").on("click", function() {
        $(".up_count_but ~ div > span").value++;
   });
});
```

Пробую сделать через jQuery - не работает, что не так?

Comment: Не используйте изображения для кода, вставляйте сам код!

Answer (score 3):

Вы выбираете `span`, а нужен `input`:

```js
document.querySelector('.up').addEventListener('click', e => document.querySelector('.up ~ div input').value++);
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Increase' class='up' />
<span>Some text</span>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <input type='text' />
</div>
```

В `jQuery`:

```js
$('.up').on('click', e => {
  let el = $('.up ~ div input');
  $('.up ~ div input').val(+el.val() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Increase' class='up' />
<span>Some text</span>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <input type='text' />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А как сделать с помощью jquery?

Comment: Обновил........

Comment: Но если у меня несколько таких блоков с одинаковыми классами, как мне обратится к input в пределах кнопки, на которую нажал? Мне ведь нужно парсить родительский блок для кнокпи

Comment: Каких блоков у Вас несколько? Таких, какие Вы привели? Оберните их в отдельную ноду и радуйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <input type="text" class="c_count" value="2"></span>
> ```

```
<input type="text" class="c_count" value="2"><span></span>
```

> ```
> $(".up_count_but ~ div > span").value++;
> ```

```
$(".up_count_but ~ div > span").text(fucntion (s) { return ++s });
```